# Correlation of sums of random variables where individual pairs have fixed correlation

Tags: correlation, random-variable

Say I have two vectors of normally distributed variables $X = (X_1, ..., X_m)$ and $Y = (Y_1, ..., Y_m)$. Each pair of variables $(X_i, Y_i)$ has the same positive correlation $r$, and all other correlations are 0. I take $n$ observations $(x_{i,j}, y_{i,j})$. Then I add up all the values of $x_j$ and $y_j$ to get sums for each observation:

$$S_x = (\sum\limits_i x_{i,1}, ..., \sum\limits_i x_{i,n})$$
$$S_y = (\sum\limits_i y_{i,1}, ..., \sum\limits_i y_{i,n})$$

My question is about the correlation of $S_x$ and $S_y$. What is the distribution of this correlation and how does it compare to the fixed value $r$?

Comment: You need to specify a _lot more_ about the covariance matrix of the $2m$ dimensional random vector $$[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m, Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_m]$$

Comment: Thank you, I will. I'm updating to ask about the case where all other covariances are 0.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I made the change but I am also curious about more general cases. Is it possible to compare the independence case with, for example, a case where the covariance matrix is nonzero everywhere but other correlations are small compared to $r$? Or is that still too general?